# Take automatically picture in OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, face-recognition

I wrote the face recognition code in OpenCV. I want the program to automatically take a picture when it detects a face

Below is whole code.

```
import cv2


face_cascade = 
cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')

video = cv2.VideoCapture(0)


while True:
    ret, img = video.read()
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, scaleFactor=1.05, 
minNeighbors=5)


for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
    cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,255,0),2)



cv2.imshow('img',img)
k = cv2.waitKey(1)
if k == ord('q'):
    break

video.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 1):

When you do

```
ret, img = video.read()
```

you do take a picture. Otherwise you won't be able to detect the faces in that frame, would you?

I assume you asked about *saving* the frame as an image.

You simply have to check if there are any faces, and save it using `cv2.imwrite`.

The following code saves in the current directory the image, and the filenames are numbered in increasing order:

```
count = 0
while True:
    ret, img = video.read()
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, scaleFactor=1.05, 
minNeighbors=5)


if (len(faces) != 0)
    cv2.imwrite('face_image_%d.png' % count)
    count += 1
```

There are probably better ways, but this shows the basic concept.